# Dojo i18n with lang.replace doesn't work

Tags: dojo

I have two template files: one for the form (loginFormTemplate) and one for the dialog (dialogTemplate). When I put them togheter I only get the i18n on my form (like ${i18n.username}, etc.), but not my dialog html it's says ${undefined}. I have clearly defined it in my nls file. Why? Here's my code when I construct my dialog.

```
        var template = lang.replace(dialogTemplate, {
            form: loginFormTemplate                
        });

        var contentWidget = new (declare(
            [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin],
            {
                templateString: template,
                i18n: i18n   
            }
        ));
```

I could create "variables" just like my form within the dialoTemplate and pass my i18n value, but I don't find it quite elegant. I just want to do it once. So, instead it would be like this.

```
    var template = lang.replace(dialogTemplate, {
            form: loginFormTemplate,
            _ok: i18n.okLabel,
            _cancel: i18n.cancelLabel
        });

        var contentWidget = new (declare(
            [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin],
            {
                templateString: template,
                i18n: i18n   
            }
        ));
```

**Here's my solution with with phusick answer (my form is notated %[]):**

```
var template = lang.replace(
                dialogTemplate,
                {form: loginFormTemplate},
                /\%\[([^\]]+)\]/g
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not by my computer, but I guess calling 'lang.replace' replaces not only {form}, but also your ${i18n.*} with undefined since only 'form' is defined when calling 'lang.replace'.

Edit: You can use 'lang.replace' with a custom pattern to avoid conflicts between i18n and string concatenation: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/_base/lang#advanced-usage